# how to using number_format on ajax codeignitier

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

need help this my code

```
save_method = 'update';
        $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
        $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
        //Ajax Load data from ajax
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('info/ajax_detail')?>/" + Kode,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
            var data = '<td><center>'+data.total+'</center></td>';              
                data += '<td><center>'+data.subtotal+'</center></td></tr>';         
                $('#table tbody').html(tbaris);
                $('#modal_form1').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                $('.modal-title').text('SEE DEtail'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
```

how to set number format into my ajax with this code

```
var data = '<td><center>'+data.total+'</center></td>';              
    data += '<td><center>'+data.subtotal+'</center>
```

ill try using this code but not working

```
data = '<td><center>'.number_format("+data.total+",2,",",".").'</center>
data += '<td><center>'.number_format("+data.total+",2,",",".").'</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to add `numberformat.js` script, see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/xiel/5688446)

By using number format function you can convert it

For desired output follow pattern

**//english format**

```
number_format( 1234.50, 2, '.', ',' ); // ~> "1,234.50"
```

**//german format**

```
number_format( 1234.50, 2, ',', '.' ); // ~> "1.234,50"
```

**//french format**

```
number_format( 1234.50, 2, '.', ' ' ); // ~> "1 234.50"
```

or just add function in your script

```
function number_format(number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep){
    decimals = decimals || 0;
    number = parseFloat(number);

    if(!decPoint || !thousandsSep){
        decPoint = '.';
        thousandsSep = ',';
    }

    var roundedNumber = Math.round( Math.abs( number ) * ('1e' + decimals) ) + '';
    var numbersString = decimals ? roundedNumber.slice(0, decimals * -1) : roundedNumber;
    var decimalsString = decimals ? roundedNumber.slice(decimals * -1) : '';
    var formattedNumber = "";

    while(numbersString.length > 3){
        formattedNumber += thousandsSep + numbersString.slice(-3)
        numbersString = numbersString.slice(0,-3);
    }

    return (number < 0 ? '-' : '') + numbersString + formattedNumber + (decimalsString ? (decPoint + decimalsString) : '');
}
```

Check sample on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/34325/

Comment: hi dhruv jadia how to use numberformat.js with my code? do u have sample code?

Comment: add function which i have provided in your script

Comment: that script can run in my ajax?

Comment: After <script> add function not in ajax

Comment: ill try using that script but still error tbaris += '<td><center>'number_format(+data.jumlah+,2,',','.');'</center></td></tr>';

Comment: @WahyuArtadianto: sample code added in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/34325/ just enter 1234.50 in textbox and check result

Comment: thats mean i have to create function? cause im using ajax json still confuse

Comment: Place your whole script code with script tag in your question I will guide you

Comment: this comment say too long by 1170 characters how to place the whole script?

Comment: success: function(data)
        {
  if (data == null) 
  {
   //alert('Kamar Kosong');
   $('#modal_kosong').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
   $('.modal-title').text('INFO KAMAR'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title
  }
  else
  {   
   var tbaris = '<tr><td><center>'+data.norm+'</center></td>';
    tbaris += '<td>'+data.pasien+'</td>';
    tbaris += '<td>'+data.alamat+'</td>';
    tbaris += '<td><center>'+data.biaya+'</center></td>';

Comment: the point of my code from this line tbaris += '<td><center>'+data.biaya+'</center></td>'; i want to set number format